# Difference between 'root :to =>' and 'root to:' in Rails Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, root

Is there a difference between these two ways of defining root in my Rails project's routes file?

> root :to => 'Something#index'
>
> root to: 'Something#index'

The second way seems like a more straight-forward way.

Comment: The second method only works when the Hash key (:to in this case) is a symbol.

Comment: @cyroxis: Not just any symbol, a limited set of symbols.

Comment: @muistooshort Good point thanks.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks for the link to the previous question!